# Serenity/Allure - Automated tests are running twice

Tags: java, maven, automated-tests, allure, serenity-bdd

I've installed serenity-bdd and allure for report generation. I want to have both serenity and allure reports, But I noticed the test suite is executing twice.

Serenity: http://www.thucydides.info/docs/serenity/

Allure: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2

I'm running the tests and report generation with:

```
mvn clean verify
```

And I have this `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>qa.tests.createusers</groupId>
    <artifactId>qa.tests.createusers</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <serenity.version>1.9.6</serenity.version>
        <serenity.maven.version>1.8.21</serenity.maven.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
        <maven.failsafe.plugin.version>2.18</maven.failsafe.plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.2</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.0</aspectj.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>0.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.failsafe.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>io.qameta.allure.junit4.AllureJunit4</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                            <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>allure-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.maven.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: why do you want to implement both the reporting what is the difference between both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause was using both failsafe and surefire plugins, just had to remove one and now the tests only execute once.

Comment: how are you getting on with creating reports between Serenity-bdd and Allure?  Are you having any problems with it, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in your pom.xml to skip surefire and handle everything through failsafe:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If you enable both the plugins, execution happens twice.